# Is there any way I can correct my username with telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Hello in python telethon is there any way i can correct or create new my username using telethon

I looked through `UpdateProfileRequest` but there is no username

Answer (score 0):

Use UpdateUsernameRequest.

This can be found here: https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=username